# Will websockets over HTTP2 also be multiplexed in streams?

Tags: websocket, http2

I am trying to clarify/understand whether `websockets` over `HTTP/2` will also be multiplexed over a TCP connection using streams. [Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8441#section-5) of RFC8441 seems to suggest it

> After successfully processing the opening handshake, the peers should proceed with the WebSocket Protocol [RFC6455] using the HTTP/2 stream from the CONNECT transaction as if it were the TCP connection referred to in [RFC6455].  The state of the WebSocket connection at this point is OPEN, as defined by [RFC6455], Section 4.1.
>
> The HTTP/2 stream closure is also analogous to the TCP connection closure of [RFC6455].  Orderly TCP-level closures are represented as END_STREAM flags ([RFC7540], Section 6.1).  RST exceptions are represented with the RST_STREAM frame ([RFC7540], Section 6.4) with the CANCEL error code ([RFC7540], Section 7).

But my confusion arises from the fact that even with HTTP/1.1, while tabs in a browser share the underlying TCP connections (e.g. chrome makes 6 TCP connections) to the same host, creating a `websocket` to the same host in different tabs leads to distinct TCP connection in each tab.

I am not sure why the difference between the two & if it is likely to be the same for `websockets` over `HTTP/2` as well.

Any experts out here who can clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But my confusion arises from the fact that even with HTTP/1.1, while tabs in a browser share the underlying TCP connections (e.g. chrome makes 6 TCP connections) to the same host, creating a websocket to the same host in different tabs leads to distinct TCP connection in each tab.

You are right that this is the current state of affairs, unfortunately, for HTTP/1.1.

RFC 8441, as you point out, has been specified to solve this problem and piggy back WebSocket "connections" over HTTP/2 streams, so it would be possible to open just one TCP connection to an origin server and use that connection for both HTTP/2 communication and for WebSocket communication.

The difference between HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 stems from the fact that HTTP/1.1 WebSocket connections cannot be (efficiently) pooled.
Every WebSocket connection is tied to a specific URI (e.g. `ws://host/path1`) and it's more typical for an application to open different WebSocket connections for different URIs (rather than many WebSocket connections for the same URI).
Because they cannot be pooled, browsers basically have to allow an unlimited number of them, a new one every time you call `new WebSocket(...)` from JavaScript.

With HTTP/2 instead, you will be able to open a new HTTP/2 *stream* inside the same HTTP/2 connection.
The number of concurrent streams depends on browser implementations, but it's typically around 100 if not more, which leaves plenty of concurrency for both HTTP/2 and WebSocket (unless the client application is really abusing WebSocket).

Fortunately, client applications won't need to be changed to leverage this feature.
When browsers and server will support it, your application will use less resources (just one TCP connection) rather than the many it's using now.

[Disclaimer, I'm the implementer of such feature in [Jetty](https://eclipse.org/jetty)]

We have seen a few browsers implementing this feature and we are finalizing the implementation of this feature in the Jetty 10.0.x server, see https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3537.

Comment: Good answer. Just one comment. Browsers typically limit the number of streams to around 1000 (though Firefox doesn’t set a limit). Servers however typically limit this to around 100 streams.

Comment: But different frames of one websocket could be transfered through different streams of one http/2 connection. Has this feature been supported by browsers and server gateways?

Comment: @weaming WebSocket frames belonging to one "logical" web socket will be transferred over only one HTTP/2 stream. In other words, there is a 1-1 relationship between a web socket and a HTTP/2 stream (not one to many like you seem to imply).

Answer (score 1):

> creating a websocket to the same host in different tabs leads to distinct TCP connection in each tab

A WebSocket connection is always a new TCP connection, since it has to perform an HTTP/S request that *Upgrades* to a WebSocket connection and is therefore no longer an HTTP/S connection if successful.  WebSocket connections are distinct and can't be shared or reused, unlike HTTP/S connections (assuming keep-alives are used).

Comment: Just to be clear: That's right for HTTP/1.1 but not any more for HTTP/2 servers implementing RFC 8441. See the other answer.